# DrawStatusText does not draw text on first call, only on subsequent calls

Tags: c++, winapi, statusbar

I have a program that used the `DrawStatusTextW()` function during the `WM_PAINT` message. When it is called, no text is drawn. However, on subsequent calls, like moving the window under the taskbar then pulling it back up, the text is drawn.

I have tried to use different flags with the function and also tried to place it in `WM_CREATE` message. No effects.

```
   RECT status_rect;
HDC status_dc;

SNDMSG(controls.status_bar, SB_GETRECT, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&status_rect));
status_dc = GetDC(controls.status_bar);
SelectObject(status_dc, status_font);
DrawStatusText(status_dc, &status_rect, L"Ready.", SBT_NOBORDERS);
ReleaseDC(controls.status_bar, status_dc);
```

It should draw the status text on the first call. I shouldn't have to move around the window so that it redraws itself.

Comment: Is that code from your `WM_PAINT` message handler? You are not using the paint DC. Why not?

Comment: Yes it is. I thought that the paint dc was only for the client area? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Where are you drawing the status bar text, if not in the client area?

Comment: By client area, I meant the "window." I thought the hdc from BeginPaint would not include the status bar and other controls. I am drawing text in the status bar.

Comment: The status bar window draws its own text. You don't need to do anything special. Just set its text when you create it.

Comment: Ok, I will try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `HWND` handles its own painting. If you draw onto the status bar while painting a parent window, the status bar's own paint handling will wipe out what you drew.

If you want to custom paint a status bar, [make the status bar be owner drawn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/status-bars#owner-drawn-status-bars) and handle the [`WM_DRAWITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/wm-drawitem) message in its parent window.